# new FileDataSource from a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Can you do something like this to get a buffered image as a file location?

```
DataSource source =  new FileDataSource(ImageIO.write(image, "png", file));
```

I'm trying to send a buffered image as a attachment using the Java Mail API without having to save the file first?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by doing a fairly lame bit of programming but it works:

```
File file = new File("temp.png");
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", file);
DataSource source =  new FileDataSource(file);
```

Then when its all done I just:

```
file.delete();
```

Comment: Nice work arround xD not ideal solution but works fast

Answer (score 3):

Build your own [DataSource](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/source/browse/activation/src/java/javax/activation/DataSource.java?r=3) class, and take your input stream from a ByteArrayInputStream wrapping the image bytes.

Something like :

```
public class ImageDataSource implements DataSource {

private Image image = null;
private String imageName = "";

public ImageDataSource( Image image, String imageName ) {
    this.image = image;
    this.imageName = imageName;
}//cons

public InputStream getInputStream() {
  return new ByteArrayInputStream( image.getBytes() );
}//met

public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
  throw new IOException();
}//met

public String getName() {
  return imageName;
}//met

public String getMimeType() {
  return "image/png";
}//met

private byte [] getImgBytes(Image image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(getBufferedImage(image), "png", baos);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //handle it here.... not implemented yet...
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}//met

}//class
```

More or less, I got not IDE :)

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, expect more questions it looks complicated!

Comment: Theres to many errors thrown up by this, I can't work them all out. Isn't there a simpler way to just get ByteArrayInputStream with out the whole class?

Comment: Turn the image into a byte array and then use ByteArrayDataSource that comes with JavaMail.

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't compile as `ImageIO.write` returns a `boolean`, `FileDataSource` expects a file/file name in its constructor